# Mapping Multiple IDs to their Email Address in Active Directory and Outputting Results to a Single File

Tags: powershell, for-loop, active-directory, io-redirection, txt

I am trying to find a method to map IDs of multiple users to their associated email addresses in Active Directory (AD), and subsequently append the outputs into a txt file, ultimately generating a single file with a list of email addresses.  Via the following command leveraging PowerShell AD Tools, I can output the email address of a certain user:

```
$user= testID
Get-ADUser $user -server ml -Properties * | Select-Object mail
```

Now I'm trying to adapt this to work across multiple users, although the method I've come across does not append or concatenate each result to the txt file.  Each new output when the loop iterates overwrites the contents of the existing text file.

```
$multiple_users = "testID1", "testID2", "testID3"
foreach ($multiple_user in $multiple_users){
    Get-ADUser $multiple_user -server ml -Properties * | Select-Object mail > ID_to_email.txt
    }
```

Any direction or insight, is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you would need to use `>>`, or using the cmdlet itseld `Out-File -FilePath .\ID_to_email.tx -Append`. Having it outside your `foreach` loop would make more sense tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala)'s helpful comment:

The ***immediate* fix is to replace `>` with `>>`** inside your [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) loop:

- [Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)  `>` is in effect an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) therefore *replaces* the target file in every iteration, which is not what you want.
- By contrast, `>>` is in effect an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) `-Append` and therefore *appends* to the target file.

However, **using `>>` *inside a loop* is best *avoided***, because it is:

- *inefficient*, because the target file must be opened and closed *in every iteration*.
- *inconvenient*, in that you must ensure that the target file doesn't exist yet or is empty before the loop, so as not to accidentally append to preexisting content.

Therefore, **it is preferable to use a [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) with a *single* `Out-File` call / `>` operation that receives the output from *all* iterations in a streaming fashion**:

Note:

- A `foreach` *statement* cannot directly be used in a pipeline and therefore with a redirection, which is why the similar [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* is used below, to which the `$multiple_users` array is *piped*, causing its elements to be processed one by one, as reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- Alternatively, you can wrap a statement such as `foreach` or `while` in `& { ... }` or `. { ... }` to allow it to participate in a pipeline; e.g.:
  `& { foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i } } > out.txt`
- The solution below applies analogously to use of the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet (which is more efficient than `>` / `Out-File` if you know the objects to write to the file to be *strings* already): use a *single* `Set-Content` call at the end of the pipeline (instead of calling `Add-Content` in every loop iteration).

```
$multiple_users | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_ -server ml -Properties mail |
      Select-Object mail
  } > ID_to_email.txt # Write ALL output to ID_to_email.txt
```

Instead of `> ID_to_email.txt`, you could use `| Out-File ID_to_email.txt` instead; explicit use of `Out-File` is *required* in the following cases:

- to force interpretation of the target file path as a *literal* path, with `-LiteralPath`, notably if it contains `[` and `]` (perhaps surprisingly, `>` and `Out-File` with the (often positionally implied) `-FilePath` parameter treat paths as *wildcard* expressions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73334614/45375)).
- to control the character-encoding to use for the output file, via the `-Encoding` parameter.