# Use PowerShell to see if a column is empty and the delete the entire row from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file, with no headlines, that looks like this:

```
"88212526";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369748";"146,79";"EUR";"6"
"88212527";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369755";"66,88";"EUR";"20"
"88212530";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369786";"143,27";"EUR";"0"
"88212532";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369809";"80,98";"EUR";"6"
"88212536";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369847";"";"EUR";"0"
"88212542";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369908";"77,16";"EUR";"9"
"88212543";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543";"5713852369915";"77,46";"EUR";"52"
```

I need a script in PowerShell that deletes the entire row if column 6 is empty.
I have tried this

```
Foreach ($line in Get-Content .\POWERMAX_DK_1.csv) {
    $linearray = $line.split(";")
    if($linearray[6] -ne "") {
        Add-Content .\myTempFile.csv $line
    }
}
```

But it don't work. The line with empty column is not removed.

Please help
/Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is twofold:

- As [Mauro Takeda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73361271/45375) points out, to access the *`6`th* element, you must use index *`5`*, given that array indices are `0`-based.
- Since you're reading your CSV file *as plain text*, the field you're looking for has *verbatim* content `""`, i.e. *including* the double quotes, so you'd have to use `-ne '""'` instead of `-ne ""` (`$linearray[5]`)

However, it's worth changing your approach:

- Use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) to import your CSV file, which in your case requires manually supplying headers (column names) with the `-Header` parameter.

  - This outputs *objects* whose properties are named for the columns, and whose property values have the syntactic `"` delimiters removed.
  - These properties can then be used to robustly filter the input with the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet.
  - In order to convert the results back to a CSV file, use a - single -call to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), as shown below (see next point).
- Using [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) *in a loop body* is ill-advised for performance reasons, because the file has to be opened and closed in every iteration; instead, pipe to a *single* call of a file-writing cmdlet - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336362/45375) for background information.

Therefore:

```bash
# Note: The assumption is that there are 8 columns, as shown in the sample data.
#       Adjust as needed.
Import-Csv .\POWERMAX_DK_1.csv -Delimiter ';' -Header (1..8) |
  Where-Object 6 -ne '' |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation \myTempFile.csv
```

*Character-encoding caveat*: In Windows PowerShell, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) uses ASCII(!) by default; PowerShell (Core) 7+ commendably uses BOM-less UTF-8. Use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need check column 6, you have to use $linearray[5], because arrays starts counting on zero ($linearray[0] should be the first element)