# Output to file in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to output some information about devices to .txt file but something went wrong. Could someone tell me what the problem is?

```
   $devices=("wsu1","wsu2")
$file="C:\reports\file.txt"
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $devices -ScriptBlock {
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem |
Select PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber | Out-File -FilePath $file
}
 & explorer.exe "C:\reports\"
```

I retrieve this message from the console:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: `$file` is not defined in the remote scope, it's defined in your local scope. If you want `Invoke-Command` to be able to see that variable defined locally you can use the `$using:` scope modifier: `-FilePath $using:file`

Comment: Agreed^, or just place your `Out-File` outside of your `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried but I did something wrong could you please edit the code and show how it should be :)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I tried that but didn't work

Comment: What didn't "work"? Did you get an error? Did it just not output information? `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $devices -ScriptBlock { ... } |  Out-File -FilePath $file`, what error did you receive when running this?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes not output information inside the file

Comment: hmmmm, weird situation then. Santiagos recommedation is: `| Out-File -FilePath $using:file` If the intention is to place it on the remote computer, otherwise it would have to be outside the loop or referencing your system.

Comment: `$devices=("wsu1","wsu2")
$file="C:\reports\file.txt"
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $devices -ScriptBlock {
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem |<br/>
Select PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber | Out-File -FilePath $using:file
}
 & explorer.exe "C:\reports\" `Did I do that correctly?

Comment: @NickS Please [edit] your question to elaborate your [mcve] instead posting any code snippet in a comment.

Comment: `Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=HR,DC=SHELLPRO,DC=LOCAL" -Properties OperatingSystem | Sort Name | Export-Csv "c:\temp\version.csv `
I found another way to find what I need thank you for supporting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your *immediate* problem is that you tried to access a *local* variable, `$file` in a *remotely executing* script block, which cannot work, and defaults to `$null`, causing [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) to report an error due to lack of an output file name.

  - In any script block that runs in a *different runspace* (notably *remotely*, on *other machines*), you need to the `$using:` scope in order to use local variable values, such as `$using:file` in this case - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for details.
- However, the fact that you're executing `& explorer.exe "C:\reports\"` in an attempt to show the output file implies that you meant to write to a *local* file, which necessitates calling `Out-File` *locally*, outside the remote script block (`{ ... }`), in a separate pipeline segment.

  - Note that this approach - piping to a *single* `Out-File` call - ensures that *all* output from the `Invoke-Command` call, across all computers targeted, is saved to the output file; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336362/45375) for more information.

```bash
devices = "wsu1", "wsu2"
$file = "C:\reports\file.txt"

# Note the placement of the Out-File call.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $devices -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem |
      Select PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber
  } |
  Out-File -FilePath $file

& explorer.exe "C:\reports\"
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help... maybe... :)

```
# Prep some stuff
$Devices = @("wsu1","wsu2")
$File = "C:\reports\file.txt"
$Results = @()

# Work for each device
foreach ($Device in $Devices) {
    $Results += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Device -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber
    }
}

# Chuck it in a file
Set-Content -Value $Results -Path $File
```

Comment: By switching to processing the devices (computers) _one by one, sequentially_, you're forgoing the benefits of calling _in parallel_.

Comment: Note that extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create _multiple_  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).